# Lettrine Parameter loversize Not Working with Drop-Cap Algorithm

Tags: macros, pdftex, parameters, lettrine, drop-cap

Consider the following code containing a macro which produces a two-color lettrine:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\input{GoudyIn.fd}
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
\newlength{\goudycorr}
\newcommand{\twocolorl}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \fontsize{85}{0}\initfamily
  \colorbox{green!80}{%
    \makebox[\height][l]{\color{black}#1}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large

\sbox0{\twocolorl{T}}%
\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.1,findent=.23em,nindent=4.5pt]{\usebox0}{he Lorem ipsum} \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

Now, given the parameter `loversize=0.1`, it seems that the displayed lettrine is rather large.

So, running the code again, but with the parameter value `loversize=-.5`, I get what appears to be exactly the same output:

[image]

I do not recall ever running into this problem in the past when I have specified a value for `loversize`.

The other parameters I am using seem to be functioning correctly.

QUESTION: What may I do so that the `loversize` parameter works properly within the above code? Could there be a problem with the package itself? Could the problem be on my end (but, again, I do not recall ever encountering a problem with this parameter before)? I compile the code with `pdflatex`

Thank you.

Comment: you are using `\fontsize{85}{0}\initfamily` so get that size any size you specify outside that context isn't going to get used

Comment: @David Carlisle `\fontsize{85}{0}\initfamily` indeed affects the size of the lettrine. If I remove it, I get an error. Are you saying that `loversize` will not work with this (needed) command, and that the only way to do what `loversize` does it to manually make adjustments to `\fontsize{85}{0}\initfamily`?

Comment: as it is with the sbox outside `\lettrine` obviously i isn't seeing any font size set by lettring. you could have the `twocolorl` directly in the argument instead of usebox then just select the font family at the current size so remove `\fonsiize{}{}` but as I said in your last question got an error on `\height` for the nested use which I didn't feel lke debugging in practice you must know what size you want so just changing th85 to whatever you need seems like not a hardship

Comment: @David Carlisle Indeed, it is not a hardship. I just wanted to know why `loversize` was not working as expected when the other parameters were. Thank you kindly for taking the time to comment on this.